# Config Symfony3 URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, debian

I use a debian server and I want change my URL `ipAdresse:9999/app.php/register` with `isAdress/register`.

I have succeed to remove the `.../web/...`. But not the `.../app.php/...`

I have a virtual host :

```
Listen ipAdress:9999

<VirtualHost ipAdress:9999>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/SuperSwungBall/web"
        DirectoryIndex app.php


        <Directory "/var/www/SuperSwungBall/web">
                AllowOverride All
                Allow from All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And a .htaccess in ~/web :

```
DirectoryIndex app.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have also tried with the default symfony ~/web/.htaccess . But, it doesn't work.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article describes a couple of examples on how to configure your webserver to route all requests through app.php with clean URL's: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html

In your case your virtual host should look something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:9999>    
    DocumentRoot /var/www/SuperSwungBall/web
    <Directory /var/www/SuperSwungBall/web>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets
    # <Directory /var/www/project>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/SuperSwungBall/web/bundles>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine Off
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It does not work. When I want to access "ipAdress:9999/register" it does not take consideration app.php. So, the script app.php is not call and it search the file "register" who doesn't exist (because it's just a path) ....

Comment: @HugoFouquet Have you checked that mod_rewrite for apache is installed and/or enabled in your webserver configuration? It seems as if it's not executing rewrite rules at all since `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` checks if the requested resource is a file or not. You can enable mod_rewrite by executing `a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: Oh ... That was it ! --'
Thanks !

Comment: @HugoFouquet Haha no problem :D Glad you got it to work.